# Google Map radius corner

Tags: css, google-maps-api-3

The `webkit-mask-image` mask moves when you scrolling the page

**[jsFiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/DZTvR/)**

```
body{
    height:1500px;
}

#wrapper {
    margin-top:250px;
    width: 300px; 
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute; /* this breaks the overflow:hidden in Chrome/Opera */
    -webkit-mask-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA5JREFUeNpiYGBgAAgwAAAEAAGbA+oJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); /* this fixes the overflow:hidden in Chrome/Opera */
}

#map1 { 
    width: 300px; 
    height: 300px;

}
```

How to make the webkit-mask-image static? Thanks

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792402/css-webkit-mask-image

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18836164/1477388

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you don't want to move the Google maps on scroll(static).

In `CSS`, it is called as **`fixed` positioning**.

```
position: fixed
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DZTvR/1/)

Comment: the supplied JsFiddle is the same as the original of the Question.

Comment: @Bart  Oops.  Forget to update it.  check this http://jsfiddle.net/DZTvR/1/ Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: Thanks! but if you have some elements are shown on the page as well, position fixed is not a solution

Answer (score 1):

Replace your data with an image-file url

```
-webkit-mask-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA5JREFUeNpiYGBgAAgwAAAEAAGbA+oJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
```