# CSS: -webkit-mask-image

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

I'm using the CSS property

```
-webkit-mask-image
```

To apply a mask over an image. However, in chrome, the mask moves as you scroll the image off the page.

How do you prevent the mask from moving? Or is it a rendering artifact?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DZTvR/ (Scroll down on the frame with the map in it).

Comment: You can use [`-webkit-mask-attachment`](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-mask-attachment) but it's only for Safari v4 and above :(

Comment: @Adrift - yeah I saw that, but, any solution for chrome?

Comment: In gChrome, when i disable then re-enable the .-webkit-mask-image property, the layout comes back in place. Can you try your masking with an image-file instead of a data:image/png;base64  ??

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478364/google-map-radius-corner

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll have to resize the .png but this seems to work for me:

```
-webkit-mask-image: url(http://s21.postimg.org/gfep7h1h3/trans_Test.png);
-o-mask-image: url(http://s21.postimg.org/gfep7h1h3/trans_Test.png);
-moz-mask-image: url(http://s21.postimg.org/gfep7h1h3/trans_Test.png);
mask-image: url(http://s21.postimg.org/gfep7h1h3/trans_Test.png);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DZTvR/13/

This should also degrade gracefully for IE <= 8.

[image]

**Edit:**

This is a better answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4579617/1477388

Example: http://search.missouristate.edu/map/mobile/examples/corners.htm

Comment: Maybe your answer is applicable to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478364/google-map-radius-corner

Comment: Yeah I should probably post it there, too; or at least a link back here from there.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1477388 This looks better, but if you scroll, you'll notice the background image move behind the clip window.

Comment: @AndyHin What browser are you experiencing this in?  I don't notice anything like that in Chrome.

Comment: @user1477388 I'm seeing this in chrome. See the following: http://www.gifsicle.com/gif/6d6ecb0 notice how the the clip window shifts and starts cutting off more and more of the bottom of the image. Also, will this solution work for dynamic image sizes?

Comment: I see the effect you are talking about.  I don't know how it can be fixed since I'm not that familiar with using masks.  As to dynamic sizes, this depends on a specifically sized PNG.  This may be a better solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579330/is-there-any-trick-to-put-rounded-corners-on-a-google-map

Comment: -moz-mask-image doesn't exist

Answer (score 3):

Replace your data with an image-file url

```
-webkit-mask-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA5JREFUeNpiYGBgAAgwAAAEAAGbA+oJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
```

About your situation, there is this issue on chromium reported by mihaip@chromium.org, Aug 26, 2013 : http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=279319  and  this one about similar subject  http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=99052

For complement of info : [-webkit-mask-attachment: No more supported in Chrome 24 and later.    Supported in Safari 4.0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-mask-attachment).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly... You should be able to use SVG clip-path and then position your wrapper div however you like.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/DZTvR/21/)**

```
body {
    height: 1800px;
}
#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
}
#map1 {
    width: 251px;
    height: 254px;
    -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipping);
    clip-path: url(#clipping);
}
svg {
    height:0;
}

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="map1"></div>
</div>
<svg>
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clipping">
            <polygon points="100,10 40,180 190,60 10,60 160,180" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Tested and working in Firefox and Chrome.