# CSS cutting image with other image

Tags: html, css, image

I have this div.

```css
.a {
  background-image: url(url_image);
  height: 400px;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-attachment: scroll
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="content1">
    </div>
    <div class="content2">
    </div>
    <div class="content3">
    </div>
  </div>
```

The `.a` image has an irregular border:

[image]

I need to put a background-image to div `.b` and obtain something like this:

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you read the following articles? [Other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792402/css-webkit-mask-image), [CSS Tricks' approach](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/), [HTML5 Rocks Article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/). I believe it is possible, but do not exactly know how. Don't know if any of the articles would help you, thats why I posted this as a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to flip the two images. The background image needs to go into `.a` and the irregular border image need to be in `.b`. Think of this as painting a picture, you start with the background then add the foreground. The foreground image needs to have a transparent background so you can see through to the background image. (This would be the blue part of the irregular background image above)

```
.a {
  background-image: url(myImage);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-attachment: scroll
}
.b{
    background-image: url(irregularBorder);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-attachment: scroll;
}
```